# Can we project into Pauli size sectors efficiently?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, computational-physics, linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a system of $L$ qubits and some Hermitian operator $\mathcal{O}$ acting on the system. We can expand $\mathcal{O}$ in Pauli strings $P_{n}$:
$$\mathcal{O} = \sum_{n=0}^{4^{L}}c_{n}P_{n}$$

for some expansion coefficients $c_{n}$. Given a Pauli string $P$, we say it has a size $|P|$ which is equal to the number of qubits on which it acts nontrivially. For example, the string $I\otimes X\otimes Z\otimes I \otimes Z$ has size 3.

What I want to do is project $\mathcal{O}$ into sectors with fixed Pauli size. If we call $\mathcal{P}_{s}$ the superoperator which projects into size sector $s$, with $s\in\left[0,L\right]$, its action on $\mathcal{O}$ is given by
$$\mathcal{P}_{s}\mathcal{O} = \sum_{n\;:\;|P_{n}|=s}c_{n}P_{n}$$

My question is if there is an efficient numerical way to implement this. "Efficient" is perhaps too vague a word, so let me propose a baseline to compare other approaches against. The obvious way to do this is to use the trace orthogonality of Pauli strings. Then in size sector $s$ we need to compute
$$\mathcal{P}_{s}\mathcal{O} = \sum_{n\;:\;|P_{n}|=s} P_{n} \times\text{Tr}\left[P_{n}^{\dagger}\mathcal{O}\right]/\mathcal{D}$$

where $\mathcal{D}=2^{L}$. This works, but it requires a huge number of computations; I'm also not interested in the individual coefficients $c_{n}$, just the final projected operator. A better method might be to compute the superoperator $\mathcal{P}_{s}$ directly, but I don't see how to do that in a nice way either.

Comment: related on qc: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28391/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Vectorize $\mathcal O$. (This comes at no cost.)
2. Transform $\mathcal O$ into the Pauli basis. This is a linear map on each qubit subspace (i.e. 4 levels in the vectorized form) independently, and can be done with $O(L4^L)$ operations.
3. Construct a vector which contains a 1 for all Pauli strings of the desired weight, and zero otherwise. (I won't count this for the cost, as this can be reused. There's certainly smart ways to do that, as it just amounts to enumerating bit strings with a certain Hamming weight.)
4. Perform a component-wise multiplication of the two vectors. (Cost: $4^L$) This gives the vectorized $\mathcal P_s\mathcal O$.
5. Transform the result back into the original basis. (Cost: $O(L4^L)$.)

Voila! Overall cost: $L4^L$, which is close to optimal. (You have to touch every entry at least once, so $4^L$ is a lower bound.)

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice way to think about it. Do you have a reference for how to do step 2 efficiently? I've never implemented that transformation myself and I imagine there are clever ways to do it

Comment: Well, I have some code which does it -- but it is a few lines. In the end you want to work out the basis transformation from |i><j| to the Paulis (this is a matrix where the columns are the entries of the Paulis, i.e. the Bell states (up to a phase)). Call the matrix T. Then you want to apply $T^{\otimes L}$ to a vector $v$. This is where you have to do it the right way: You don't build $T^{\otimes L}$. Rather, you do by applying one T after the other, i.e. you transform T into a matrix (size $4\times 4^{L-1})$ and do matrix-vector multiplication with T.

Comment: ... "transform *v* into a matrix", of course.